# How many religions did we see Sazed preach?

Tags: religion, mistborn, cosmere

Throughout the first two books in the *Mistborn* series - and even once or twice in the third, if I recall correctly - Sazed, the scholar of historical religions, will occasionally tell other crewmembers about one of these religions, usually with the suggestion that it might be one to suit them.

At the end of the third book, when Sazed

> takes the power of both Preservation and Ruin, he remakes the world to how it used to be a thousand years ago, using his knowledge of ancient religions.

Many of the religions mentioned at this point are the same ones we've actually seen him preach in earlier books. I liked this, since it made clear that

> the final twist of Sazed taking the power, although it seems at first sight like a random plot twist invented at the last minute just to surprise the reader, was in fact planned from the very beginning.

This dramatically increased my respect for Sanderson as a writer. I'm now wondering whether *all* the religions Sazed preached in earlier books were mentioned in this final stage, or just a few of them. Hence my question:

#### what were all the religions Sazed preached over the course of the trilogy?

<sub>**Clarifications:** I'm looking for the religions where he actually talked about some of their beliefs, not those where he only mentioned their names, nor those he considered privately in order to discredit them in *The Hero of Ages*.</sub>

Comment: So you want everything mentioned outside the finale in *Hero of Ages*?  Does that include the sequel series?

Comment: @Radhil No, just the original trilogy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sazed lists off six religions that he uses to remake the world after he takes up Harmony. One of them is not named (merely that it has something to do with animals), but the other five are ones Sazed has mentioned before:

- Bennet was mentioned in *The Final Empire*, Chapter 29, as being focused on maps. Sazed uses this one to rebuild the continents to their original forms.

  > It was a good religion, Master Kelsier. It focused on discovery and knowledge—to these people, the making of maps was a reverent duty
- The Nelazan people followed Trelagism, the worship of Trell. I don't think this religion is named in the original trilogy, but it's one of the few old religions that is followed post-Harmony, and shows up in the Wax & Wayne novels. This religion allowed Sazed to restore the planet's orbit.
- The Cazzi (spelled "Canzi" at the end of the book but obviously the same religion) people followed an unnamed religion that focuses on the form of the human body. Sazed uses it to restore the nobles and Skaa back to their normal forms. Sazed mentions this religion early on, praying over a dead body using a Cazzi prayer. It's also mentioned in the Chapter 27 epigraph, again spelled "Cazzi":

  > Yes, Rashek made good use of his enemy’s culture in developing the Final Empire. Yet, other elements of imperial culture were a complete contrast to Khlennium and its society. The lives of the skaa were modeled after the slave peoples of the Canzi.
- Sazed tells Clubs about Dadradah, noting at the end that this was the "last religion he ever taught", and used it to put everything back to its natural color.

  > 'They thought art drew one closer to God,' Sazed said. 'They were most interested in color and hue, and they were fond of writing poetry describing the colors they saw in the world around them.'
- Larstaism is the religion that Kelsier's wife followed. Sazed also mentions that, of all the religions he knew, he spent the longest time considering if this one was "true", because there were no inherent contradictions in it.

  > Larstaism was a difficult one for Sazed to measure. [...] And yet, the religion didn't seem very ... well, religious. It had focused on art, not the sacred in the usual sense, and had centered around donating money to support monks so that they could compose poetry and paint and sculpt works of art.

**However**, there are a number of other religions that Sazed mentions by name during the series but not in the big climax. While remaking the world, he implies that he uses something from *every* religion, but not all of them are called out by name. Others that we know exist include:

- Valla - this religion lasted a long time, including long after its leaders died out.
- Jaism - Sazed mention this one to Kelsier as a religion "with power", explaining that its followers were very zealous.
- HaDah - Sazed performs a HaDah funeral for a Skaa that was killed by the Deepness.

  > This day, the memories he selected were of HaDah, a southern religion with an agricultural diety.
- Duis - He prays to Duis when he gets caught by the koloss army.

  > He chose a god - Duis, a god once said to watch over wearied travelers - and said a quick, silent prayer.
- The Terris religion - This one has no name, but [Word of God](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=977#182) says that it was rather advanced, and knew about Realmatic theory. Sazed eventually discovers that the First Generation Kandra were all practitioners of the Terris religion.
- The Atalsi religion - Also unnamed, it revolved heavily around luck, but incorporated a lot of scientific theory as well.

  > They thought that different colors were indications of different kinds of fortune, and were quite detailed in their descriptions of light and color.

Comment: OK, this covers the religions that were mentioned at the very end. But how many *other* religions (if any) did he preach throughout the series which *weren't* mentioned again when he takes up the power of Harmony?

Comment: Those are covered in the last sentance, I'm digging up quotes now.